# How Java client get a single returned byte form server?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java client program which can send a single character command to the server through the internal IP network then the server will return a single byte to report the status such as (00101001 means position one, four and six is on). I found that my client can send the character to server but fail to get the returned char command. Anyone can offer the suggested code for my reference? Thanks in advance!

Following is my testing code for your reference. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
String host = "192.168.1.1;

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, 6789);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

outToServer.writeBytes("^");
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
clientSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: want to show us some code?

Comment: Show us your code.  For a start, we can't advise you unless you give us details of the protocols and APIs that you are trying to use.

Comment: post your code. welcome in advance

Comment: "Fail" is not a problem description. Failed *how?* All you need is [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the server is a machine so it is a black box to me, I only have the command set manual such as e = turn on position 1, f = turn on position 2, .... ^ = get the position status etc. I will try to review my code and summarized my result and post again. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the questions you've been asked. Define "fail". What happens instead? Wrong answer? Nothing? Computer explodes?

Comment: Hi EJP, sorry for my ambiguous description, the fail means my client can not print the feedback byte from server, so I don't know the exactly problem. Because the server is a hardware box and not with me now. I will try to review my code with your comment tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting one character it doesn't make sense to call `readLine().` By definition, a line includes a line terminator, and if you're only expecting one character it will have to be the line terminator itself. Use [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) as I already stated in commentary.